# passing args to a DLL function Procedure called with not enough arguments (20 bytes missing)

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to call a dll function using ctypes and getting an error. How can I get more info of what is wrong with my call?

dll function header:

```
DLL_API BOOL WINAPI DDSSetFrequency(int index, double frequency, int* wavePointNum, int* TNum);
```

python code

```
from ctypes import *

hantek = cdll.LoadLibrary("E:\Programmer's Guide\DLL\DDS3X25Dll.dll")
print hantek.DDSSearch()

wavePointNum = c_int()
Tnum = c_int()
frequency = c_double(10000000.0)
index = c_int32(1)

hantek.DDSSetFrequency(index,frequency,byref(wavePointNum),byref(Tnum))


1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3x25.py", line 17, in <module>
    hantek.DDSSetFrequency(index,frequency,byref(wavePointNum),byref(Tnum))
ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (20 bytes missing) or wro
ng calling convention
```

Comment: Try to load the DLL as `windll` and define `argtypes` and `restype` of the `hantek.DDSSetFrequency` function. http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html

Comment: changing to windll helped some, no more error. but I still don't get the return values in the wavePointNum and Tnum. can you explain what you mean by defining argtypes and restype?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes

Comment: a made changes per docs
    hantek = windll.LoadLibrary("E:\Programmer's     Guide\DLL\DDS3X25Dll.dll")
    hantek.DDSSetFrequency.argtypes = [c_int, c_double,     POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int)]
    hantek.DDSSetFrequency.restype = c_bool

still not getting anything back from the function.  the ones that don't require any parameters execute fine.  I'm now trying the same dll from VB to see if it works there...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not still working on this project, but in case you are (and for posterity's sake), I am providing a [link to a python wrapper](https://github.com/AIMAtlanta/Hantek_1025G) I've written for the HT1025G that demonstrates a working interface.  The `set_frequency` method is a bit persnickety, and I've found better luck with (the undocumented) `set_divisor` method.